# Azure service bus topic subscription expiration date

Tags: azure, subscriptions

Lets say I do have a topic A and multiple subsciriptions to this topic. Is there any expiration date for any subsription or do they exist for as long as the topic exists?

It is important to know because in case we have a subscription which is not used for a long period of time is it cleaned at some point or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create topics and subscription as **temporary objects** by setting the  `autoDeleteOnIdle` property which is set to the duration for which an entity must be idle (unused) before it is automatically deleted..

Read more here:
[Temporary entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration)

Comment: Thanks. But in case I have created not temporary subscription it will not have any expiration date, correct?

Comment: As far as I know it won't have any expiration date.